# lookup table data with interpolation from reference list

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation, date-and-time

I have data as:

```
f1 ={{"16:19:46", 34.49, 59.73, 44.54, 40.3, 32.1, 68.32, 44.64, 36.67}, {"16:19:49", 34.45, 59.88, 44.54, 40.3, 32.15, 68.3, 44.64, 36.67}, {"16:19:52", 34.41, 60.03, 44.54, 40.3, 32.15, 68.32, 44.64, 36.71}, {"16:19:55", 34.37, 60.15, 44.54, 40.34, 32.19, 68.27, 44.64, 36.74}, {"16:19:58", 34.32, 60.27, 44.54, 40.34, 32.19, 68.08, 44.64, 36.74}, {"16:20:01", 34.28, 60.39, 44.5, 40.37, 32.19, 67.96, 44.6, 36.78}, {"16:20:04", 34.24, 60.54, 44.5, 40.37, 32.19, 67.73, 44.6, 36.81}, {"16:20:10", 34.1, 60.69, 44.46, 40.4, 32.19, 67.73, 44.56,  36.81}, {"16:20:13", 34.1, 60.84, 44.46, 40.44, 32.15, 68.01, 44.56, 36.85}, {"16:20:16", 34.06, 60.94, 44.46, 40.44, 32.15, 68.01, 44.51, 36.85}, {"16:20:19", 34.06, 60.97, 44.46, 40.44, 32.19, 68.05, 44.51, 36.85}, {"16:20:22", 34.1, 60.97, 44.42, 40.44, 32.19, 67.93, 44.51, 36.85}, {"16:20:25", 34.15, 60.9, 44.42, 40.47, 32.19, 67.9, 44.51, 36.85}, {"16:20:28", 34.19, 60.81, 44.42, 40.44, 32.19, 67.88, 44.51, 36.85}, {"16:20:31", 34.28, 60.69, 44.42, 40.44, 32.19, 67.79, 44.51, 36.85}, {"16:20:34", 34.32, 60.51, 44.46, 40.4, 32.23, 67.82, 44.56, 36.81}}
```

and the input time as

```
f2={"16:19:50", "16:19:54", "16:19:57", "16:20:01", "16:20:05","16:20:09", "16:20:13", "16:20:17","16:20:20", "16:20:24", "16:20:28", "16:20:32"}
```

with a given time in f2, I want to return interpolation values for data from column 2 to column 8 of the f1. The final table includes the first column from f2 and 8 other columns containing interpolated data from columns 2 to 8 of f1.

Could you please let me know how to extract data from F1 based on the given data in F2?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `TimeObject` to interpret the strings as times and use `TimeSeries` to obtain an interpolation. The option `ResamplingMethod` allows you to specify an interpolation method.

```
f = TimeSeries[Transpose[{
     TimeObject /@ f1[[All, 1]],
     f1[[All, 2 ;; 8]]
     }],
   ResamplingMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 3}
   ];
times = TimeObject /@ f2;
```

Now you can map `f` over the list `times` or use `f` as a (`Listable`) function like this:

```
f/@times
f[times]
```

And

```
Transpose[{f2,f[times]}]
```

inserts `f2` as first column to the table.

Comment: Thank you Mr Henril Schumcher. Please let me know how to add the time of f2 before the f to form the table? thank you

Comment: You mean like this?

Comment: Thank you. I prefer this: {{"16:19:50", 34.43666666666667`, 59.931481481481484`, 44.54`, 
  40.29802469135802`, 32.151111111111106`, 68.30765432098765`, 
  44.64`}, {"16:19:54", 34.38395061728395`, 60.11148148148148`, 
  44.54`, 40.327160493827165`, 32.17716049382716`, 68.29876543209876`,
   44.64`}}

Comment: Aha. You changed the input data. Well, it still works with that, no?

Comment: thank you. that work. I change the data because I find the difference of the format of time in f1 and f2 may cause problems. It is ok to delete the lase 3 digits. I have joint the two data as Join[Transpose[{f2}], f[times], 2]. Thank you very much

Comment: You're, welcome. (Indeed, `Join[...,...,2]` is also a good idea.)